# Does homebrew require me to give my user account write access to /usr/local?

Tags: permissions, homebrew

Some software that I am interested in using is most easily installed using homebrew. However, my understanding from a few years ago was that homebrew requires me to give my user account write access to /usr/local. Is that still the case? If so, homebrew is not really an option for me as I rely on the traditional permissions to prevent me shooting myself in the foot.

Comment: The following link may be helpful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/are-my-permissions-for-usr-local-correct